# AngularJS not giving back PHP call

Tags: php, angularjs, post

I used an Angular $http post in sending email using PHP but when I try to get a console log, I get the **index.html** content. I'm using ng-view for rendering the html template of the **contact_us.html**

**Controller.js**

```
..
  $scope.sendEmail = function(){ 
       var request = $http({ 
       method: "post", 
         url: window.location.href + "MailerProcess.php", 
         data: { 
           name: $scope.contactInput.name,  
           email: $scope.contactInput.email,  
           message: $scope.contactInput.message  
         }, 
         headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}  
       }); 

       request.success(function(data){ 
         console.log(data); 
       }) 

       .error(function(data){ 
         console.log(data); 
       }); 

       $scope.contactInput = angular.copy($scope.defaultForm); 
       $scope.contactForm.$setPristine(); 
     };

..
```

**MailerProcess.php**

```
<?php

# Data from angular POST
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
@$name = $request->name;
@$email = $request->email;
@$message = $request->message;

$myemail = "someemail@gmail.com";

$name = strip_tags($name);
$email = strip_tags($email);
$message = strip_tags($message);

  if ( $name && $email && $message) {
    if($email!="" AND !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $data = array(
        "message" => "Please enter a valid email address.",
        "type" => "error"
        );
        echo "Please enter a valid email address.";
     }else {
        $message = "
        Someone has sent you a message from Some Website:

        Name: $name
        Email: $email
        Subject: Email from Some Website

        Message:
        $message 
            ";
        mail($myemail,"Email from Website",$message);
          $data = array(
        "message" => "Your message was sent, Thank You!",
        "type" => "success"
        );
        echo "Your message was sent, Thank you!";
        }
    }else{
    $data = array(
        "message" => "There was an error on the system, please try again later.",
        "type" => "error"
        );
    echo "There was an error on the system, please try again later.";
  }
?>
```